# Equivalent T-SQL to Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I am trying to replicate my T-SQL script written in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to Microsoft Access Query Design.

I have pretty much figured out most of the script except the following;

```
convert(char, 'Approved') as status
```

or rather

```
status = 'Approved'
```

How would i write any of those two into Microsoft Access SQL Designer?

Comment: `SELECT "Approved" AS Status`

Comment: @Jim thanks Jim, that worked. If you want it as the answer, go ahead and i will vote it. Thanks again!